# More than 4 column for content in TYPO3 6.x.x

Tags: typo3

Is there a way to add more column to TYPO3?

In the past I used to add additional column in ExtTables.php (http://www.lacisoft.com/blog/2009/11/06/additional-columns-in-typo3s-web-page-module/), but since TYPO3 6.x.x the `mod.SHARED.colPos_list` is no longer support, so in backend I only see 4 standard column and nothing else...

Any sugestions, manuals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution - `Beckend Layout` - and tutorial on http://blog.sebastiaandejonge.com/articles/2012/july/26/implementing-typo3s-backend-layouts/ site